# jquery.tablesorter: scroller has bad header width in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, alignment, tablesorter, scroller

using tablesorter and the scroller widget, I noticed the header width is badly computed in IE 11 (also tested the last Firefox: this is OK). The problem is that, if no horizontal scroller is needed, the header width considers yet that there is one. Are there enough data to display the horizontal scroller, then this is OK.

[image]

My params are:

```
$("#mytable").tablesorter(
{
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ["zebra",'filter','scroller','uitheme'],
    widthFixed: true,
    sortList: [[0, 0]],
    widgetOptions:
    {

        scroller_height : 600,
        scroller_upAfterSort: true,
        scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
        filter_cssFilter: 'tablesorter-filter',
        filter_childRows: false,
        filter_startsWith: false,
        filter_ignoreCase: true,
        filter_searchDelay: 300,
        filter_functions:
        {
        }
    }
});
```

This only interesting option I found is:

```
scroller_barWidth: -7,
```

This can force the header to be aligned to the body but only with no scroller (now with a scroller the header is too large).

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date scroller widget? Are you seeing the same issue in [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html)?

Comment: I have indeed the last version of tablesorter / scroller widget / jquery

Comment: Can you modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mqv16pd4/) to show me the issue?

Comment: This seems to be crazy but this only happen with an even number of rows.. The explanation is probably a tag that is not closed properly anywhere in my code... I am checking it

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the problem only happens with a even number of rows, if there are text area within, and if these text areas have a padding (was 5px 10 px) => I removed the padding and it's OK